# Android - Multiple onReceivedHttpAuthRequest with WebView

Tags: android, ssl, webview, basic-authentication

I have a problem with my WebView and the b asic authentication. I have created the following `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
   Log.d(this.toString(),"onReceivedSslError error:"+error.toString());
   handler.proceed();
}

@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
   Log.d(this.toString(),"onReceivedHttpAuthRequest host:"+host+" realm"+realm);
   handler.proceed(HttpHelper.HTTPUSERNAME, HttpHelper.HTTPPASSWORD);
}
```

The App normally authenticates right at the webserver (`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` will be called about 5 times and then the page will be loaded). But sometimes there is just a blank page and i can see in Logcat about 2-3 calls of `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`. Then I have to close the App and restart it. It doesn't help to reload the activity with the `WebView`. Perhaps its a problem with https which will be also used?

And yes, I already used google... but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22654157