# SSL certificate issue with basic authentication

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate, basic-authentication

I'm trying to load an SSL page with basic auth in a webview, but even though i run proceed() in onReceivedSslError and usr/pwd is correct I can't get past onReceivedHttpAuthRequest. If I remove the haveAuthenticated check in the code below it just loops endlessly with auth requests, like if the credentials were wrong. Seems like it won't accept the certificate when trying to authenticate.

Adding the basic auth header didn't change anything, any other way to get around this?

```
package com.my.package;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String USERNAME = "com.my.package.USERNAME";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Activity thisActivity = this;
        final MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        // Get usr + pwd
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USERNAME);
        final String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PASSWORD);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Webview
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // SSL and authentication
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            Boolean haveAuthenticated = false;

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.d(thisActivity.getLocalClassName(), "Error " + description);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                Log.d(thisActivity.getLocalClassName(), "Auth " + handler.obtainMessage());
                if (!haveAuthenticated) {
                    Log.d(thisActivity.getLocalClassName(), "!haveAuthenticated/" + handler.obtainMessage());
                    haveAuthenticated = true;
                    handler.proceed(username, password);
                } else {
                    Log.d(thisActivity.getLocalClassName(), "haveAuthenticated/" + handler.obtainMessage());
                    haveAuthenticated = false;
                    setResult(401, mainActivity.getIntent());
                    thisActivity.finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Log.d(thisActivity.getLocalClassName(), "SSL Error " + error.toString());
                handler.proceed();
            }

            // Trying basic auth headers
        String up = username + ":" +password;
        String authEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(up.getBytes(), 0);
        String authHeader = "Basic " + authEncoded;
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Authorization", authHeader);

        webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.webview_url), headers);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that it works on some devices but not all, e.g. not on Asus Padfone 2 with the following logs.

```
03-25 08:42:52.363: D/WebViewActivity(30030): SSL primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=*.company.com,OU=IT,O=COMPANY ASA,L=Here,ST=Norway,C=NO,2.5.4.5=#1320476557596744525532556f634c42487675656f484b2f654a794a554954676356;
03-25 08:42:52.363: D/WebViewActivity(30030): Issued by: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA,O=GeoTrust\, Inc.,C=US;
03-25 08:42:52.363: D/WebViewActivity(30030):  on URL: https://test.company.com/some/page.aspx
03-25 08:42:52.733: D/WebViewActivity(30030): Auth { what=0 when=-1d1h30m25s561ms }
03-25 08:42:52.733: D/WebViewActivity(30030): !haveAuthenticated/{ what=0 when=-1d1h30m25s562ms }
03-25 08:42:52.823: D/WebViewActivity(30030): Auth { what=0 when=-1d1h30m25s655ms }
03-25 08:42:52.823: D/WebViewActivity(30030): haveAuthenticated/{ what=0 when=-1d1h30m25s656ms }
```

Comment: Is the SSL certificate used by the the web server issued by a CA or self signed?

Comment: As you see in the logs it's issued by GeoTrust SSL CA. It's a wildcard cert. Certification path is 1. GeoTrust Global CA, 2. GeoTrust SSL CA, 3. *.company.com.

Comment: If it works on some devices but not others, most likely the devices it doesn't work on don't have an appropriate GeoTrust certificate from which to trace the certificate chain to the *.company.com certificate.